# DynamoDB Appsync Query on multiple attributes

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

My app uses AppSync resolvers to fetch data from DDB and return it to our front-end. One table we have is for Notifications. A Notification can be either pending or default (non-pending). The table itself has a primary key of notification_id and we have a GSI called userIndex to grab the notifications for a user, with a sort key of timestamp.

In the app, I show all notifications in a list, pending first and then default. Given that a user may have many notifications, I'd like to implement pagination to fetch a batch at a time. The only way I've been able to do this is to

1. change the query to include a `isPending` parameter, which I use as a filter expression for the query to only return notifications that are isPending or isNotPending.
2. Store two "nextTokens", one for each isPending and isNotPending, along with corresponding lists.
3. Make separate queries for pending/non-pending, and use the filter to return to the appropriate list.

This is obviously inefficient and I am re-reading data from DynamoDB. My question is, given my DynamoDB table/requirements, is there a way I can paginate so that I can get all the pending notifications first (sorted by timestamp) and then all the default notifications next (sorted by timestamp) by using one query and one `nextToken`

I've seen the use of `@model` and `@key`, but I haven't been able to make it work in my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. There is a hard limit on returns for a Dynamodb query - and that cannot be bypassed. the only way to make use of `nextToken` is another query.

However, it is also worth noting that the FilterExpression *happens after the data has already been retrieved* and is filtered client side. It does not reduce the documents pulled from the query - only whats displayed. So the next token is still going to be (relatively) the same for each query. You can instead filter it yourself after the call before the next pagination query and save yourself a little bit in terms of multiple calls.